# Oracle sum is incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a "report" with SQL*Plus that adds data from an OLTP table and emails the results to a bunch of users.

I have discovered a problem though. The total in the table `CATEGORIES` is wrong

```
SQL> select * from CATEGORIES;

DATE              P4         D1          D2          P5          P6       P7       TOTAL            
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------- -----------            
14-OCT-14    200,623  2,320,173   6,807,295  17,861,027  17,386,567  803,982  45,379,667
```

**It should be "45,379,307" instead of "45,379,667".**

This table has NUMBER(10) columns and the base table has NUMBER columns (no precision) to store the categories P4, D1, D2...

The total in the `CATEGORIES` table is obtained from the base table `CATG_ACTV` thusly.

```
UPDATE CATEGORIES
   SET TOTAL = (SELECT SUM(total_catg_count) FROM CATG_ACTV);
```

Why is the total incorrect? Is it because of the NUMBER columns being incorrectly sized? How can fix this?

Comment: Um, 200,623 + 2,320,173 + 6,807,295 + 17,861,027 + 17,386,567 + 803,982= **45,379,667**.  Why do you think it should be 45,379,307?

Comment: Given the data from your categories table, those do up to the total.  You're not giving enough information on why you think the answer is incorrect, or the data that makes up your categories data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know what you did.  When you did the arithmetic, you transposed digits.  You used `200263` instead of `200623`.

`200263 + 2320173 + 6807295 + 17861027 + 17386567 + 803982 = 45379307`

Comment: Gave you +1 back. You're have gold badges and high rep, so this wasn't just a n00b job. I'm sure we've all stared at code for hours trying to find why code gives a "wrong" answer. Syntax and fatal errors are easy compared to this. Sometimes best to step away and get some fresh air and come back, or bring over a coworkwer's second set of eyes, or even posting on SO. I'm sure you were like omg duh when you found out the solution.

Comment: I have a fever and a cold...and I stayed up coding way past my bed time. I know what I mistakenly typed. My apologies to all. Thanks to all for your time. I wish I could down-vote my own post...(omg duh)...Going back to bed.